# Word that means “unburnt”

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

If it was raining, I might say “stay dry!”  If it was cold, I might say “stay warm!”

If there was a wildfire and I wanted to say “stay not burned up!” then what word would be best?

Comment: I think you need a phrase rather than a single word…don’t get burnt!!!

Comment: Perhaps a bit too generic for your specific goal, but "Stay safe!" would certainly suffice.

Comment: Stay tender. (Instead of crispy).  But then there’s probably a play on tender/tinder if I stopped to think about it.

Comment: The opposite of cooked is raw, but that's a slightly different intention than burned.

Comment: Stay in touch and intact.

Comment: @Mitch I could definitely imagine “stay raw” as a slang term for avoiding fire :)

Comment: Evacuate!!.....

Comment: Seriously, there is no room for jokes about wildfires right now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a single word or a phrase specifically for that situation. Simply saying "Stay safe!" would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep%2Fstay%20cool):

> **Keep cool!**
> *idiom*
>
> to remain calm
> *It is important to keep/stay cool in a crisis*

Of course, you won't get burnt either.